# How to show sqlite data on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have a local sqlite database, and a lightweight mini-httpd server on the same linux host.
I'd like to provide web visualization of the data contained on the sqlite database.

I've checked Google Charts and it basically does what I need, but doesn't directly connect to sqlite. Should I feed the data manually with javascript?

What is the best way for showing result of sqlite queries to a web browser?

Comment: http://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/ check this link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show statistic with Google Charts you have to provide the data with a proper format.
You need an app where to make request and connect to the DB running on the webserver, make the query with javascript to that app and then pass the data to G charts.
You have also tons of libraries to show data, all you have to know is the licence your site will be running. [jchartfx](http://www.jchartfx.com) if really powerfull